# How to access properties from messages.properties file in spring controller using annotation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to access properties from messages.properties file in spring controller using annotation.

Please provide an example.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 19):

I used MessageSource :

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

...

private EventByDate createDefaultEventByDate(String date, Long barId, String locale) {
    Event defaultEvent = new Event();
    Locale localeValue = new Locale(locale);
    defaultEvent.setTitle(messageSource.getMessage("default.event.title", null, "DefaultTitle", localeValue));
    defaultEvent.setText(messageSource.getMessage("default.event.text", null, "DefaultText", localeValue));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to define property place holder in your dispatcher-servlet.xml file like below.

```
<util:properties id="messageProperties" location="/messages.properties"/>
```

You need to change the path of your messages.properties file.

And then you can just access the property file value with help of `@Value` annotation.

```
private @Value("#{messageProperties['your.message.code']}") String message;
```

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: i tried it but its doesn't seems to be work. i m using spring 3.0.

Comment: What is the problem?? Can you show the configuration in the question?

Comment: Also show me where have you put your message.properties file in the project.

Answer (score 0):

[image: message.properties file location]

Following is dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

`<context:annotation-config/>
<util:properties id="messageProperties" location="/messages.properties"/></beans></pre>`

And as you mentioned for controller i am using same code with my properties. and its unable to resolve @Value annotation.