# Access application.properties from messages.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization

I need to access properties from application.properties in messages.properties:

**application.properties**

```
max-size=3
```

**messages.properties**

```
alert.error=You can only save {max-size} items.
```

Not working:

```
{max-size}, #{max-size}, ${max-size}
```

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252159/how-to-access-properties-from-messages-properties-file-in-spring-controller-usin) thread, but I need it outside of any Java file.

**Update:** the maven approach works within application.properties files but not between application.properties and messages.properties. Shouldn't there be an order? If file A has key a but when file B is parsed first a is not available in B yet, is it?

Snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
```

"#{alert.error(${@environment.getProperty('max-size')})}"

Comment: What is the value of getting this properties from application.properties in build time? Spring best practice is to inject values for properties with @value.

Comment: @IssamELATIF what would be the syntax for that? alert.error=You can only save ???max-size??? items.

Comment: the syntax should be alert.error=You can only save {} items and then use MessageSource to get messages. I deleted my answer as it is the same as what @g00glen00b suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Either you replace it using build tools (Maven/Gradle/...), or you use a parameter in your message, like this:

```
alert.error=You can only save {0} items.
```

Now you can autowire your `MessageSource` and retrieve your `maxSize`:

```java
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
@Value("${max-size}")
private int maxSize;
```

And then you can use it this way:

```java
messageSource.getMessage("alert.error", new Object[]{maxSize}, locale);
```

This solution allows you to use your message for other sizes as well, rather than making it just 3.

If you want to use it in your views (eg. with Thymeleaf), you can do:

```html
<p th:text="#{alert.error(${@environment.getProperty('max-size')})}"></p>
```

Comment: I prefer this implementation as it is more spring compliante

Comment: The message dialog eventually is triggerd in an angular directive after a server response has failed, so Thymeleaf and Java are no options.

Comment: If this message should be visible after a server response failed, then you have to send that message from your server (= Java) to your front-end (= AngularJS). You can use `messageSource.getMessage()` in your Java code as soon as your response should fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building in maven you can filter the message.properties at build time.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 1):

you can do via maven by invoking a resource plugin goal https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

where **messages.properties** is placed in src/main/resources

```
<build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/application.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

invoke `mvn resources:resources`